# DataTable row Selection not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable

```html
<p:dataTable id="db"
    value="#{notificationBox.notificationsList}"
    var="notificationForm" 
    rows="15"
    emptyMessage="${msgs.getMessage('table.empty.message')}"
    paginator="true" 
    paginatorPosition="bottom"
    rowKey="#{notificationForm}"
    selection="#{notificationBox.notification}" 
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} ( ${notificationBox.notificationsList.size()} ${msgs.getMessage('table.records')} )"
    selectionMode="single" 
    tableStyle="height:430px">

    //Rest of the code
```

Here If I am selecting any row, I am going for an ajax call (same as in primefaces instant row selection example). Ajax is inside the Datatable .

```html
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificationBox.onRowSelect}"   
    oncomplete="carDialog.show();" />
```

My Backing Bean class -

```
private List<NotificationForm> notificationsList;
public NotificationForm notification;
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    LOGGER.info("Here. +"+notification);
}

//Setter and Getters.
```

The problem is if I select any row, The "notification" is coming as null. I can not process further. Please help. Any alternate approach is also welcome.

Edit:-

My Managed Bean Scope -

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>notificationBox</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.comviva.workflow.ui.notification.NotificationBox</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>notificationDao</property-name>
        <value>#{notificationDaoService}</value>
    </managed-property>
    <managed-property>
        <property-name>userInfoDao</property-name>
        <value>#{userInfoDaoProxy}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: What's the scope of your managed bean?

Comment: Your `rowKey` is suspiciously strange. Does PrimeFaces eat that? Does it have equals/hashcode implemented? I never tried it like that, but I'd rather expect to see a `#{entity.id}` here.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, It's in view scope. I have updated the details.

Comment: @BalusC, I have edited it as rowKey="#notificationForm.notificationId}" now. But still I am getting null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have your `p:dataTable` wrapped in a `h:form` tag? This actually works for me:

**NotificationBox (@ViewScoped)**

```java
package com.mycompany;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NotificationBox {

    public class NotificationForm {

        Integer notificationId;

        String name;

        public NotificationForm(Integer id, String nam) {
            notificationId = id;
            name = nam;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Integer getNotificationId() {
            return notificationId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "NotificationForm [notificationId=" + notificationId
                    + ", name=" + name + "]";
        }
    }

    private List<NotificationForm> notificationsList;

    public NotificationForm notification;

    public NotificationBox() {
        notificationsList = Arrays.asList(new NotificationForm(1, "Form1"),
                new NotificationForm(2, "Form2"));
    }

    public NotificationForm getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }

    public List<NotificationForm> getNotificationsList() {
        return notificationsList;
    }

    public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getObject());
    }

    public void setNotification(NotificationForm notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }

}
```

**index.xhtml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="db" value="#{notificationBox.notificationsList}"
            var="notificationForm" rows="15"
            emptyMessage="${msgs.getMessage('table.empty.message')}"
            paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            rowKey="#{notificationForm.notificationId}"
            selection="#{notificationBox.notification}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} ( ${notificationBox.notificationsList.size()} ${msgs.getMessage('table.records')} )"
            selectionMode="single" tableStyle="height:430px">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{notificationBox.onRowSelect}" />

            <p:column>
        #{notificationForm.name}
        </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: There was also an [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4089) with (at least) PrimeFaces 6.2, that prevented the event when clicking on a checkbox (instead of somewhere in the row) for row selection.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue can occur if your xhtml page imports jquery library. I removed it and the selection worked.